# How to exclude Id from focusout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focusout, focusin

With Jquery, focusout is just called when you click anywhere out of the focused area when "focusout" is set.

How do I exclude some id(s) from activiting the "focusout" function. ?

e.g here.

You have an input text field ( id="A")that hides some div on focus and shows that very div when it's out of focus, so but now it obviously will show the div when you click anywhere out of this ("#A") input field.

Question is, how do you set some id(maybe a select field(Id="B" next to it), not to fire off the "focusout" function. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Do you mean the new ID you're clicking on, or the ID you're leaving?

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: Any id that will be clicked which is not the originator of the "on focus" event. I don't think the code will enlighten you @Tim, it's gonna add more mist instead, lets just use layman's terms, "English".

Answer (score 1):

Try using `relatedTarget` event property:

```
$('#id').focusout (function (e) {

    if (e.relatedTarget && e.relatedTarget.id === 'dontFocusOut') {
        return;
    }
    //do your thing

});
```

Comment: I'd love to also try this one since unbind just kills the function in a way that after clicking the unbinded div, "focusout" just dies. , but this related target doesn't run.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't run"? Note that `event.relatedTarget` might be null if you your related target is not part of your document. In any other case it should be the element receiving focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can `unbind` the `focusout` when you click on a div. This may return some expected results, and at some point in your code you'll probably want to rebind it. See here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/hdCFA/

```
$("input").on("focus", function() {
    $(".hidden").show();
});
$("input").on("focusout",function() {
    $(".hidden").hide();
});

$(".clickable").on("mousedown", function() { 
    $("input").unbind("focusout"); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<input />
<div class="hidden">Hidden div</div>
<div class="clickable">Click me</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clickable { background:blue; }
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Good one, easy and straight forward. Thanks.

Comment: Lol, so this doesn't unbind only the div, but just kills that function completely, from the unbinded Id you can't click somewhere else and have focusout continue working.

Comment: Right, as I mentioned, you're going to have to rebind at some point in your code. Without knowing the application it's hard to say when to rebind, but this should give you a good head start on a solution.

Comment: Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/hdCFA/1/ It uses a few variables and `e.preventDefault();` to, hopefully, accomplish what you're after.

Comment: Actually, you may not even need the variables. Those were leftover from another solution I was trying. http://jsfiddle.net/hdCFA/3/