# jQuery: focusout to exclude some elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-focusout

focusout on input field will trigger every time the specific input looses its focus.
But, I want to exclude some specific a tag from triggering that focusout function

Example:

```
<input type="text" id="name_input">
<a id="apply_name">SAVE</a>
```

Then the focusout function:

```
$("#name_input").focusout(function(e) {
  //do something here
});
```

Clicking on "#apply_name" also triggers focusout function of an input. How can I exclude that specific element ID from triggering it.
Note: I tried some tricks already posted on StackOverflow and none of them seams to work...

Comment: why don't you do this filtering in your callback?

Comment: try something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sVM74/1/

Comment: As far as I know there is no direct solution to this as the focusout will trigger before the click event... try the above hack

Comment: @ArunPJohny ha ok, you make question more clear now ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff I'm still doubtful whether it has to be an answer until OP clarifies whether that was the problem he was looking at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way of doing this is checking what your target id is

```
var evt;
document.onmousemove = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    evt = e;
}
$("#name_input").focusout(function (e) {
    if (evt.target.id == "apply_name") {
        //apply_name clicked
    } else {
        //focus out and applyname not clicked
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sVM74/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "blur" - event.

```
$("#name_input").on("blur", function(e) {
    //your code
});
```

Comment: blur doesn't bubble, but seems strange this could be the issue because INPUT cannot contains any element

Answer (score 0):

Solution from [How to exclude Id from focusout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372942/how-to-exclude-id-from-focusout)
Added .hasClass which I also needed:

```
$('#id').focusout (function (e) {

    if (e.relatedTarget && $(e.relatedTarget).hasClass('dontFocusOut')) {
        return;
    }
    //do your thing

});
```