# How can i exclude some element from focusing out?

Tags: javascript

I have input. When i focus out on that input the focus out event gets triggered.
But under that input i am having

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <ul>
     <li>1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

i want focus out event to be triggered when the inputs gets focus out - but when this under - when it is clicked - i don't want the focusing out of the input to ba happened.

I tried this here:

[How to exclude Id from focusout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372942/how-to-exclude-id-from-focusout)

```
$('#id').focusout (function (e) {

    if (e.relatedTarget && e.relatedTarget.id === 'dontFocusOut') {
        return;
    }
    //do your thing

});
```

but it does not work for me - in `event.relatedTarget` i always get null.

Comment: That is a weird requirement. What if the user clicks on `myDiv` and *then* 10 seconds later clicks on another element... You will not have the `focusout` event triggered. Please provide a snippet that includes the `input` element, preferably a runnable snippet (use the toolbar), so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: can you also explain why you don't want the focus out - perhaps there is a better way to achieve your desired result rather than removing the focus out

Comment: @Pete i am builing autocomplete component. So clicking on the dropdown - dropdown options are opened. The user can choose some of the options below. If he choose some option. then focusOut is triggered automatically and i can't listen to other changes where i am picking up the chosen autocomplete option

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this:

```js
function my_fun(){
  alert('Focus Out');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeHolder="After focusout it will work" onfocusout="my_fun();" />
```

Comment: There is no answer on my question here